# Sencha proxy in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: xml, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a problem with Firefox 
[ERROR][Ext.data.proxy.Server#buildRequest] You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.
but in another bowser all work!

```
 extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
requires :['Ext.data.reader.Xml'],
config : {
    model : 'Colors',
    storeId : 'colorConfig',
    autoLoad : true,
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : 'test.xml',
        reader : {
            type : 'xml',
            rootProperty : 'test',
            record : 'color'
        }
    }
}
```

when i write

```
    var store = Ext.getStore('colorConfig');
    var references = Ext.Array.pluck(store.data.items, "data");
```

mozilla return data.url = null and all another browsera return right url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha have bug in src\touch\src\data\reader\Xml.js need replace function `getNodeValue`(line 189)

```
getNodeValue: function(node) {
    if (node && node.firstChild) {
        return node.firstChild.nodeValue;
    }
    if (node && node.nodeValue) {
        return node.nodeValue;
    }
    return undefined;
},
```